# Statusbar Color won't change in v21

Tags: android, colors, statusbar

it feels like, I have searched the whole internet for this... I'm currently writing an app, in which the statusbar color should be red in v21 (Lollipop) and above. The current code from values-v21/styles.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/darkWhite</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

This code does not work. The strange thing is, it only doesn't work in v21, in v22 (Android 5.1) it is shown as fully working. Do anyone know how I get it working on v21?

(Sry for bad English)

Comment: can you give manifest file's theme name?

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme" - is this right?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me but I use

```
item name="colorPrimaryDark"
```

Without 'android' before the attributes.

Comment: Didn't work, `Error:(6, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.`

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it doesn't work, if v21 isn't the targetSdk in the Manifest.